# How to sort/get desired URLs properly in WorkBench and Run it in TestPlan of JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, record, workbench

I have to record and run Jmeter test using WorkBench so that I have recorded using Proxy[See the image].
[Lists all the URLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4ixS.png)

I know I can sort/get the urls by using 'URL Patterns to Include' option in HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder. When recording it lists out all the URLs including .gif, .png, .ico etc.

[URL Patterns to Include](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRfRG.png)

I have two doubts to clear.

1. When recording what is the criteria to give in 'URL Patterns to Include' - to record desired URLs only. (Desired URLs I meant is for example, if I am recording a website developed in PhP, I need all PhP links only. ie, home.com/index.php, home.com/contact.php, home.com/about.php). Now it records all the URLs where I cannot see the desired links. How to get .php or main link URLs(we see in browser URL)?
2. Regarding running a test in Test Plan contains the URLs that I have cut-paste from WorkBench(recorded using Proxy), do we need to add all the recorded URLs including .gif, .png, .ico etc or just add the specific URLs(say home.com/about.php) only? If I run using only the specific URLs, whether the result will be correct as we excluded other URLs like .gif, .png, .css etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **don't need to record** these `.gif`, `.ico`, etc. files separately as this is not how real browsers work.

Real browsers do main request to the HTTP endpoint followed by concurrent download of so called **embedded resources**: images, scripts, styles, etc. In order to make your JMeter test to behave more like a real browser you need to:

1. Exclude these requests from recording. Click "Add suggested excludes" button in the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) (or even better re-record your test scenario using JMeter Recording Template feature)

   [image: JMeter Suggested Excludes]

   You can create a recording test plan by selecting `File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create` from JMeter's main menu.
2. When it comes to test execution add [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) to your Test Plan, switch to the "Advanced" tab and tick `Retrieve All Embedded Resources` and `Parallel Downloads` boxes

   [image: JMeter HTTP Request Defaults Embedded Resources]

   If there are images, banners, whatever coming from external servers you can filter them as well via `URL(s) must match` box in form of [Perl-5 compatible regular expression](http://www.pcre.org/).

See [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) article for more information on dealing with embedded resources in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Also, I have tried recording using Badboy software, BlazeMeter Plugin for Chrome and Selenium IDE for Firefox browser. These 3 will help to find out/record the direct links gone through browser without any other URL patterns such as .gif, .png, .css, etc and save as jmx file that can be imported to JMeter. I hope using these 3 ways to record will work fine as we do Recording using Proxy in JMeter. Right?